# Just downloaded R Version 4.0.0 and am not able to use it?

Tags: r

This is the error that comes up when I tried to do my first command. I've tried downloading the earlier version but that didn't seem to help. What should I do?

```
Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into �C:/Users/clair/Documents/R/win-library/4.0�
(as �lib� is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0)
```

Comment: you need to install Rtools looks like. are you trying to build your own package?

Comment: Can you check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Comment: why don't you do what it tells you to do? ... it even gave you a link to the webpage

Comment: Rtools isn't an R package, it's a set of tools you need to install separately to allow you to compile packages within R on windows. See akrun's link for all the details.